# Comparing date columns between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The project I'm working on requires me to find out which 'project' has been updated since the last time it was processed. For this purpose I have two dataframes which both contain three columns, the last one of which is a date signifying the last time a project is updated. The first dataframe is derived from a query on a database table which records the date a 'project' is updated. The second is metadata I store myself in a different table about the last time my part of the application processed a project.

I think I came pretty far but I'm stuck on the following error, see the code provided below:

```py
lastmatch = pd.DataFrame({
    'projectid': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
    'stage': ['c', 'c', 'v', 'v'],
    'lastmatchdate': ['2020-08-31', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-24',
                      '2020-08-31']
})
lastmatch['lastmatchdate'] = pd.to_datetime(lastmatch['lastmatchdate'])

processed = pd.DataFrame({
    'projectid': ['1', '2'],
    'stage': ['c', 'v'],
    'process_date': ['2020-08-30', '2013-11-24']
})
processed['process_date'] = pd.to_datetime(
    processed['process_date']
)

unprocessed = lastmatch[~lastmatch.isin(processed)].dropna()

processed.set_index(['projectid', 'stage'], inplace=True)
lastmatch.set_index(['projectid', 'stage'], inplace=True)

processed.sort_index(inplace=True)
lastmatch.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(lastmatch['lastmatchdate'])
print(processed['process_date'])

to_process = lastmatch.loc[lastmatch['lastmatchdate'] > processed['process_date']]
```

The result I want to achieve is a dataframe containing the rows where the 'lastmatchdate' is greater than the date that the project was last processed (process_date). However this line:

```
to_process = lastmatch.loc[lastmatch['lastmatchdate'] > processed['process_date']]
```

produces a `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`. I think it might be a syntax I don't know of or got wrong.

The output I expect is in this case:

```
                lastmatchdate
projectid stage              
1         c        2020-08-31
```

So concretely the question is: how do I get a dataframe containing only the rows of another dataframe having the (datetime) value of column a greater than column b of the other dataframe.

Comment: please show your expected output

Comment: your example semms to be wrong, because for stage c last match date its not greather than process date fror stage c bot are same, or maybe you dont want to group them by stage?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect a real case. The dates were indeed wrong.

Comment: anyway, you are checking those dates taking into account, project_id, or stage or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merged = pd.merge(processed, lastmatch, left_index = True, right_index = True)
merged = merged.assign(to_process = merged['lastmatchdate']> merged['process_date'])
```

You will get the following:

```
                process_date lastmatchdate  to_process
projectid stage                                       
1         c       2020-08-31    2020-08-31       False
2         v       2013-11-24    2013-11-24       False
```

Answer (score 1):

you 've receiver `ValueError` because you tried to compare two different dataframes, if you want to compare row by row two dataframes, merge them before

```
 lastmatch = pd.DataFrame({
        'projectid': ['1', '2', '2', '3'],
        'stage': ['c', 'c', 'v', 'v'],
        'lastmatchdate': ['2020-08-31', '2013-11-24', '2013-11-24',
                          '2020-08-31']
    })
    lastmatch['lastmatchdate'] = pd.to_datetime(lastmatch['lastmatchdate'])
    
    processed = pd.DataFrame({
        'projectid': ['1', '2'],
        'stage': ['c', 'v'],
        'process_date': ['2020-08-30', '2013-11-24']
    })
    processed['process_date'] = pd.to_datetime(
        processed['process_date']
    )
    
    df=pd.merge(lastmatch,processed,on=['stage','projectid'])
    
    df=df[
        df.lastmatchdate>df.process_date
    ]
    print(df)
      projectid stage lastmatchdate process_date
0         1     c    2020-08-31   2020-08-30
```